# Plotting standard deviation function using WolframAlpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to plot a standard deviation function using WolframAlpha's function plotter and my function looks like this:

$SD(Y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=2}^{k}\frac{k(i-1)}{ (k-(i-1))^2 }}$ where k goes from 1 to 50.

And I've written my function like this in the plot

> plot sum( (k(i-1))  /   ((k-(i-1))^2)  ) from i=2 to k from k=1 to 50

But I can't seem to put a square root over the whole sum without an error. How can I write my standard deviation function and get the graph?

Comment: Sometimes with wolfram alpha, you have to use wolfram language input. Like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[Sqrt[Sum[%28k+%28i+-+1%29%29%2F%28k+-+%28i+-+1%29%29^2%2C+{i%2C+2%2C+k}]]%2C+{k%2C+1%2C+50}])

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know such a thing existed

Comment: If you look at your original input of `sum( (k(i-1)) / ((k-(i-1))^2) ) from i=2 to k` and click on the 'A' symbol, use the Wolfram Language plain text input.

Comment: Sorry I don't see the 'A' symbol, where is it?

Comment: when you hover you mouse over the `Sum:` box, there will be an `A` symbol below with a list of other options.

Comment: Ok yes I see it now